# Can open PSE API using browser but not using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to record data from Philippine Stock Exchange website. I have found that they have an endpoint which is http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html?method=fetchHeaderData&company=29&security=146

I can clearly access it using any browsers except when I go into incognito mode where I'm being shown with a content saying Access Denied and it never stops loading. When I try to access it using PHP I'm quite sure that what is happening is the same as the later.

I'm trying to access it using PHP to no avail, here are the attempts I tried:

1. file_get_contents
2. cURL with user agent
3. cURL with temporary cookies
4. Tried all in localhost and in live server.

Code:

```
$c = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $c);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $c);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "method=fetchHeaderData&ajax=true&company=29&security=146");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
```

I don't have any clear idea on why and how does this happen. Can someone explain to me why it happens and what are the possible solutions (PHP only if possible)

I have reviewed other developer's approach on this API (They all implemented it using Java) and it is just a simple POST request and it is done. I have not verified though if their code is still working. I can't post links to their repository (limited).

---

**SOLUTIONS:**

**Problem 1. Can't access API**

```
$posts = array(
  "method"=>"fetchHeaderData",
  "ajax"=>"true",
  "company"=>29,
  "security"=>146
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$posts);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
```

It seems I have two different problems. I can now access and use the API using the code above. No need for other options. Turning the post data into array fixed the problem.

**Problem 2. Access Denied**

On the problem about the Access Denied, it is cookie related. Answered below by @Wayne.

---

Unfortunately, I can't accept two answers.

Comment: When I visit that link, I'm also seeing access denied. Are you sure they don't have a whitelist on that endpoint that holds your external IP? Otherwise you might have logged into their platform before you visited that link?

Comment: At my end url is not opening at all

Comment: Alive to Die, it seems to work now!!! wth?

Comment: Find the error
`if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    die ('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}`

Comment: @Glubus that endpoint is supposed to be public which is being used in displaying the header part for a selected company in this page http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html?id=29&security=146&tab=0

Comment: @delboy1978uk I have tried that and it doesn't work as the connection doesn't die. When no timeout is set, the page will eventually die with a 500 internal server error. Referring to its behavior when the Access Denied page is displaying. It is loading indefinitely, I don't know the correct term for it.

Comment: @EdcelCeliz I understand, but it seems that the endpoint is whitelisted to only be accessed by the webpage requesting that header. Any outsider IP will be blocked by the whitelist. Unless you are somehow able to get the endpoint working in your browser, I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. convert your post data in array then pass this array in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

```
$posts = array(
  "method"=>"fetchHeaderData",
  "ajax"=>"true",
  "company"=>29,
  "security"=>146
  );
$c = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $c);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $c);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$posts);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: I tried it in local and live environment but it didn't work.

Comment: In my localhost its not working(going to infinite). but after adding array. Its giving output

Comment: I have retried it and in localhost it is not working. However, when I tried it again in server, it magically worked. I will try to omit some parts to provide a better code, I don't know how turning it into array worked but I guess it is with the html entities. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because they have their server setup to stop you from doing that. **They are securing the data** with a cookie.

---

**Cookie details**

When you visit the site http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html it gives you a cookie as it knows you are a human visitor.

In your browser tools enter

**document.cookie**

to see your cookie. It will provide you an individual the data because you have the cookie.

Remove the cookie

document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";

and visit

http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html?method=fetchHeaderData&company=29&security=146

**without going to get a cookie** http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html first you will get the **403 (Forbidden)**

Also they do not have jsonp with a callback so an ajax request will violate the cross domain security. Requests for the JSON must be from pages that originate from their domain or an approved domain.

---

**Why would they do that.**

Likely their licence to the information does not allow them to give it to other websites, or they need/want to get paid to provide the information to other websites. Or they have terms of use for the information.

---

**Where can you get the data ... data wants to be free**

I don't see anyplace on their site http://www.pse.com.ph where they have API information and how to request permission to access it.

Programable web has been the number one source for finding APIs, [they have 96 stock APIs listed](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/96-stocks-apis-bloomberg-nasdaq-and-etrade/2013/05/22) ... Obviously I can not just copy their data and past it here, but one of these API may work for you?